# Show that this measure cannot exist

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mu\colon\mathcal{B}([0,1])\rightarrow \{0, 1\}$ be a measure satisfying $\mu(\{x\})=0$ for each $x\in[0,1]$ and $\mu([0,1])=1$.

I want to prove that this measure cannot exist.

*Proof*:

Let $A\in\mathcal{B}([0,1])$ be the smallest subset where $\mu(A)=1$. This smallest subset must exist, because of the monotonicitiy of the measure. Hence we have $\mu(A\cap\mathbb{Q})=\mu(A)-\mu(\mathbb{Q})=\mu(A)-\mu(\bigcup_{x\in \mathbb{Q}}\{x\})=1$ in contradiction to the assumption that $A$ is the smallest subset satisfying this property.

It this correct?

Comment: Did you mean to require $\mu([0,1])=1$ not $0$?

Comment: "This smallest subset must exist, because of the monotonicitiy of the measure.": This is vague and would need to be argued more carefully, if it's true at all.  The most natural way to try to construct a "smallest" such set would be to take $A = \bigcap_{\mu(B) = 1} B$, but that is an uncountable intersection so you can't conclude that it is measurable or that it has measure 1.

Comment: There's a typo in the question, or you're leaving something out or something - defining $\mu(E)=0$ for all $E$ gives a counterexample to the question as stated.

Comment: I might instead proceed as follows: show that for every $x \in [0,1]$ there exists $n$ such that the open interval $(x-1/n, x+1/n)$ has measure zero.  Then use compactness.

Comment: And btw if $\mu$ is Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$ then there does not exist a smallest $A$ with $]mu(A)=1$. There exists such a set that's smallest "up to null sets", but that doesn't do what you need here

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Can you elaborate on why such a smallest set must not exist? Wouldn't there be infinite sets with measure one, if a smallest would not exist?

Comment: It's obvious that (for Lebesgue measure) there is no smallest set of  measure $1$. If $\mu(A)=1$ and $x\in A$ then $\mu(A\setminus\{x\})=1$.

Comment: Not that it matters, since there are other problems, but the equation $\mu(A\cap\mathbb{Q})=\mu(A)-\mu(\mathbb{Q})$ was supposed to be $\mu(A\setminus\mathbb{Q})=\mu(A)-\mu(\mathbb{Q})$, right? (If so: This does not give a contradiction, because it could be that $A\setminus Q=A$.)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Indeed, this is another error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your set $A$ need not exist. One way of proving this result is to consider $a\equiv \inf \{x: \mu [0,x]=1\}$. It is easy to see that $\mu [0,a)=0$ and  $\mu [0,a]=1$ which forces $\mu \{a\}$ to be $1$, a contradiction.

Some details: $\mu [0,a-\frac 1 n]=0$ for all $n$ by definition of $a$ and this gives $\mu [0,a)=0$. Similarly, $\mu [0,a+\frac 1 n]=1$ for all $n$ and this gives $\mu [0,a]=1$.

Comment: Why does the set $A$ not have to exist? This is basically what you are assuming with your constructed $a$. If the set $A$ would not exist, we had an infinite set of intervalls for the measure is 1, a contradiction. Could you elaborate on this?

Comment: @EpsilonDelta A minimal set  of posotive measure need not exisst. How do you get your $A$? Are you taking the intersection of all sets of positive measure? Could that not be an uncountable intersection?

Comment: Note: This answer is a Probabilist's favorite: it says that if a CDF takes only the values $0$ and $1$ then  it must a single jump at some point.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** A measure satisfying $\mu(\{x\})=0$ for every $x$ is called "continuous", presumably because it follows that the function $x\mapsto\mu([0,x])$ is continuous.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\mu([0,1]) = 1$, $\mu$ is $0-1$ valued, and singletons have measure $0$, either $\mu([0,1/2]) = 1$ or $\mu([1/2,1]) = 1$.

Label whichever one of these intervals that has measure $1$ as $I_1$. Proceed to construct a sequence $\{I_n\}$ of closed intervals satisfying
$$I_1 \supset I_2 \supset I_3 \supset \cdots,$$
$\mu(I_k) = 1$ for all $k$, and $\ell(I_k) = 2^{-k}$.

The continuity of the measure implies $$\mu \left( \bigcap_kI_k \right) = 1,$$ but the nested intervals property guarantees the intersection is a singleton.